# Work with a PHP array in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

Is it possible to work with a PHP array in jQuery ?

For example, if I have the following PHP code, how can I work on it with jQuery ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Volvo
    [1] => BMW
    [2] => Toyota
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Make a JSON data structure out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for example

```
<?php 
    // PHP 5.4 min for the [] syntax   
    $a = ['Volvo', 'BMW', 'Toyota']; 
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.version.here"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // init some JavaScript but don't pollute global scope (window)
    (function (arr) {
        $(arr).each(function (a) { console.log(a); });
    }(<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$php_array = yourArray; 
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

OR the better way:

```
var jqueryarray = <?php echo json_encode($php_array); ?>
```

Then, you can start looping on the jqueryarray variable.

Answer (score 0):

This will send your PHP out looking like a javascript array, which jquery/javascript will pick up on, since PHP is parsed by the server and jquery by the client.

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C");
$imp = "'".implode("', '",$list)."'";
echo "
  <script>
    var list = [" . $imp . "];
  </script>
";
```

The output looks like this:

```
<script>
  var list = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
</script>
```

However, if you want to send the array back to PHP, you need to use AJAX.